# Apply logic to only certain keys in array using PHP's foreach

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

My script outputs an array:

```
$person = array(
    'name' => 'bob',
    'age' => '27',
    'sex' => 'male',
    'weight' => 'fat'
    // ...etc.
);
```

Sometimes the keys in `$person` have no values - and I want to check for this. However, I don't give a chicken nugget about `$person['age']` or `$person['weight']`, I only want to check the other keys in the array aren't empty:

```
foreach ($person as $key => $value) {
    if ( $key != 'age' || $key != 'weight' ) {
        if ( empty($value) ) {
            echo 'you dun goofed';
        }
    }
}
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This matches all keys:

```
if ( $key != 'age' || $key != 'weight' )
```

You probably want:

```
if ( $key != 'age' && $key != 'weight' )
```

or something like (scales a bit better...):

```
if (!in_array($key, array('age', 'weight')))
```

Comment: Clearly I'm an idiot. Thank you. Gotta wait 10 mins to accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to check if both of them are empty:

```
if ( $key != 'age' && $key != 'weight' );
```

**Code:**

```
foreach ($person as $key => $value) {
    if ( $key != 'age' && $key != 'weight' ) 
    {
        if ( empty($value) ) 
        {
            echo "$key field is empty<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

**Codepad: http://codepad.org/hEHVru4a**

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If says if key is not `age` or not `weight`. If this is correct;

so try this:

```
foreach ($person as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array($key, array('age','weight')) {
        if ($value == FALSE) {
            echo $key . ' is empty';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `X != Y || X != Z` is always true when `Y != Z`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the || to an &&. As it is, the if statement will be true for both age and weight

Answer (score 1):

Because if the key does equal `'age'` it will still NOT equal weight, and tell you that you dun goofed. And vice-versa. Try this:

```
if ( !in_array ($key, array('age','weight')) ) {
```